# Free software for parental control of MSN and Internet in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet, parental-controls, windows-live-messenger

I'm looking for some ***free*** parental control software **for Windows XP** that will allow restriction of applications (MSN, Internet (IE or FF)) based on time of day and or hours used.

E.g.  no MSN or Internet after 9pm or for only 1 hour/day.

I realize there are many commercial packages out there, however I don't want/need extensive keyword filtering, content filtering, logging etc. just simple time limits.

Any suggestions or personal reviews of applications appreciated.

Comment: Your children are smart, they will pass those kind of software lock fast. The best way is to limit them yourself.

Comment: @Livinloud - my children are indeed smart ;-) - however the PC in question is not targeted for my kids - and the simplest of solutions would not be defeated.

Comment: Other people's kids are always dumber than yours, it's well known :-]

Answer (score 1):

It may seem like overkill, but upgrade to Windows 7!  Perhaps Improved Parental Control would be another reason to upgrade from XP.  That said I do realize there would be a cost.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option in this case.  Its an old XP machine that likely wouldn't run Win 7 or Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Some home routers have access controls built in so that you can limit internet access.  If you have a home router, you might want to check your documentation or explore the configuration to see what is available.  I know the Linksys WRT54G has such controls.

Comment: AFAIK, Most that I've seen will let me block IP's and Ports, but nothing time/date based.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in the router with software like [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is probably your best bet, but there are easier methods if you're not worried about them being bypassed.